# xjc for only part of schema

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jaxb

We plan to use JAXB for mapping of xml to objects. Our requirement is such that we will be working on only one part of the document (slightly biggish), so we want to only convert that part (a fragment) to objects. Hence, we do not want to create classes for all the elements in the xsd.

How can we ask xjc to ignore certain elements or consider specific elements while generating classes?

From what I have read, we can use bindings file to customize the behaviour of xjc, but what can we put in schema for ignoring elements.

Comment: are you using the xsd or java annotations to generate classes?

Comment: We are using xsd, but this xsd is for the entire document not just the part that is needed. Also, I am not sure how can I use java annotations to generate the classes? Can you point me to some link?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem by now? I have the same problem. To make it worse: the unused parts of the XSD makes XJC throw errors, because two similarly named types boil down to the same file name on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external binding file to configure XJC to use an existing class instead of generating one. You can leverage this by pointing to a non-existant class to get JAXB to exclude parts of your XML Schema.  In the example below the non-existant class `com.example.Fake` will be used for the complex type named Foo.

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="yourSchema.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Foo']">
        <jxb:class ref="com.example.Fake"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc  -d outputDir -b binding.xml yourSchema.xsd
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The only thing is my schema is quite big so will have to write bindings for many elements....which I guess would be equal to writing POJOs for the required parts and putting annotations on it. Any easier way? I guess I sound too lazy :P